# how to apply a specific commit from a git remote repo different than the original

Tags: git

I just cloned [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) from github. There is a python3 [bug](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/pull/111) that was corrected by this [commit](https://github.com/xrmx/unoconv/commit/fc59dd90f03cf88f4cf16c07204809f2239284ee).. I'm not sure how to simply apply that commit (as in applying a patch to what I have) using git

I tried `git fetch` and `git pull` but nothing happens.. I can simply just copy and paste the raw file over the one that I have, but that wouldn't be the *git* thing to do. ideas?

**update:**

it turns out the patch was made a user other than the original author (ie he [forked](https://github.com/xrmx/unoconv) the repo). so the question now is.. how do I apply his patch, but still have the original repo as the remote repo I update from?

Comment: where do you want the apply the fix to? where have you tried to fetch/pull from? (or did you just try those commands exactly like you listed them?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have a single commit applied, `git cherry-pick <hash>` is the way to go.
If that commit is in another repository, you can just add that as another remote, do a `git fetch all` (*no* `git pull`!) on that remote and perform the cherry-pick then.

Comment: that only works if the commit exists in the same repo i've originally cloned from.. see updated question

Comment: i added another repo and called xrmx.. but then `git fetch all` doesn't work.. what I did is I had to fetch that extra remote specifically (ie `git fetch xrmx`) then I was able to apply the patch..